# Gerando Logs com Linha do Erro e Arquivo que deu Erro (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, log, stack-trace

Eai galera, estou tentando gerar Logs para uma aplicação web .ASP, porem não consigo encontrar o método em C# correto para encontrar a Linha e o Arquivo onde está ocorrendo o erro.
Dentro da excessão encontrei o método StackTrace porem ele traz todas essas informações juntas, gostaria de saber se alguem pode me ajudar gerar um log que traga o Arquivo, Método e Linha do Erro separadamente e "bonitinho".

Desde já agradeço e tamo junto!!!

PS: segue abaixo o meu código

```
        try
        {
            
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.Subject = "EMAIL ENVIADO PELO FALE CONOSCO";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mail.To.Add("contato@seudominio.com.br");
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("contato@seudominio.com.br");
            mail.From = from;
            mail.Body = "MENSAGEM ENVIADA PELO USUÁRIO \n";
            mail.Body += "Nome: " + Nome.Text + "\n";
            mail.Body += "Email: " + Email.Text + "\n";
            mail.Body += "Mensagem: " + Mensagem.Text + "\n";


            //2. CONECTAR AO SERVIDOR DE EMAIL E ENVIAR
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.seudominio.com.br";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("contato@seudominio.com.br", "suasenha");
            smtp.Send(mail);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Erro.Text = "Houve uma falha inesperada ao enviar o e-mail. <br>";

            string conteudo = "Data         : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n" ;
            conteudo += "Mensagem       : " + ex.Message + "\n";

            //Dicas: procure respostas em http://msdn.com.br
            //Está no ex (Exception do catch)
            conteudo += "Arquivo        : " + "..." + "\n";
            conteudo += "Método         : " + "..." + "\n";
            conteudo += "Linha do Erro  : " + ex.StackTrace + "\n";

            //Está em outro lugar
            HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
            conteudo += "Browser        : " + browser.Browser + " - " + browser.Version + "\n";

            string host = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
            conteudo += "IP             : " + ip[5].ToString() + "\n";
            conteudo += "--------------------------------------------------\n";




            //DEFINE O CAMINHO ONDE O ARQUIVO SERA GRAVADO.
            string caminhoVirtual = "~/Falhas/Log.txt";
            string caminhoFisico = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(caminhoVirtual);

            //grava a exceção no arquivo log.txt
            File.AppendAllText(caminhoFisico, conteudo);
                           

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um app console pra ilustrar uma ideia de como você pode fazer isso segue:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
                //Como tem apenas um erro segue a ideia de array começando em 0 por isso o Framecount -1 se você for trabalhar com mais de um erro precisará ajustar esse trecho
                var stFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount -1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Método: {stFrame.GetMethod().Name} \r\nArquivo: {stFrame.GetFileName()} \r\nLinha: {stFrame.GetFileLineNumber()}");
            }
        }
```

Abaixo os resultados obtidos:

```
Método: Main 
Arquivo: C:\teste_erro\Program.cs 
Linha: 18
```

Comment: Olá Lucas, reproduzi seu código e solucionou o meu problema. Muito obrigado!